# Want to convert big numbers into exact number string

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, biginteger

```
const num = 100000000000000000000001

console.log(num.toString()) //1.0000000000000001e+23
console.log(num.toLocaleString('fullwide', { useGrouping: false })) //100000000000000010000000
```

I want to convert num in to exact string like 1000000000000000000001. I tried these two methods but non of them works. At last I want to split these individual digits into an array and array doesn't works on number that's why i want to convert it to exact string.

Answer (score 1):

Since ECMAScript 2020 you can use [`bigint` data type](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_bigints.html), which will have a `toString()` method that works as you want it.

```js
// note the "n" which denotes this is a bigint
const num = 100000000000000000000001n;
// verify it's a bigint
console.log(typeof num);
// print the number
console.log(num.toString());
// put inidividual digits in array
console.log(num.toString().split(""));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but there's a problem as the num variable is an output of another function then how can put n to the end of it?

Comment: You can use the wrapper constructor `BigInt(yourNumber)`. For more information and some things to consider please read [this](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_bigints.html#the-wrapper-constructor-bigint). It is important to know that *Numeric literals with absolute values equal to 2^53 or greater are too large to be represented accurately as integers* when using `number` datatype. Therefore if your function returns something bigger than that it won't be represented correctly if it is not using *bigint*. Then, you can't get the precise value from the function because it is not there.